# How to trigger parent window function from iframe a>href click, ionic2/angular2

Tags: ionic2

I am currently working on ionic2 app.

In one ionic page I have embedded an Iframe

```
<iframe id="iframeId" #iframe src="./epubpages/s006-Lesson-001.xhtml" width="100%" height="100%" (load)="onLoad()"></iframe>
```

inside that page .ts file

```
@ViewChild('iframe') iframe:ElementRef;
onLoad()  {
console.log('me');

let doc =  this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
var h = doc.getElementsByTagName('a');
console.log(this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument.document);
for(let i=0; i<h.length; i++){
  h[i].onclick = function(){
    window.parent['sayHello'];
  }
}}
sayHello(){
    console.log("Saying Hello from ");
}
```

When I click on the IFRAME page link, the funciton SayHello() which is on parent page is not getting called. I dont know if it is possible or not, but this is my requirement to trigger the parent page function.

I am using ionic2.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm now with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this on [github](https://gist.github.com/jaydson/1780598) which may help. Basically look for a window.blur event and use that. Here is the code from github:

```
var myConfObj = {
   iframeMouseOver : false
}
window.addEventListener('blur',function(){
  if(myConfObj.iframeMouseOver){
    console.log('Wow! Iframe Click!');
  }
});

document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER_ID').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
   myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = true;
});
document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER_ID').addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
   myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = false;
});
```

I ran into a similar issue in an Angular2 app and used the following (in case other Angular2 users come across this issue):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  host: {
    '(window:blur)': 'myHandler($event)',
    '(window:click)': 'myHandler($event)'
  },
  ...
})
... // rest of the component
```

Adding both `'(window:blur)'` and `'(window:click)'` helps to handle cases where the user clicks elsewhere in the window that's not part of the iframe.

I hope this helps!